# Is this a bug of the sklearn logistic regression?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am new here, so excuse me for any mistakes.

So, I have the following problem: I am simulating a logistic regression data set with a single independent variable (X) and a response variable Y. Then I create two design matrices: One containing X and the other containing X and X, i.e. twice the same variable. Then I fit two models using the two different design matrices. Obviously the coefficient estimates should be "identical", that is intercept_1 = intercept_2 and coef_1 = sum(coef_2). But this is not the case. Also a likelihood ratio test should return a p-value = 1, but this is also not the case. Why is this happening?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss
from scipy.stats import chi2
N = 100
X = np.random.randn(N)
XX = np.array([X, X]).T
probs = np.exp(X)/(1+np.exp(X))
Y = np.random.binomial(1, probs, N)
myLogReg = LogisticRegression(solver = 'newton-cg', max_iter=1000, fit_intercept=True, random_state=1)
myLogReg.fit(X.reshape(-1, 1), Y)
y_prob = myLogReg.predict_proba(X.reshape(-1, 1))
currentMinusTwoLogLik = 2*len(Y)*log_loss(Y, y_prob)
print(myLogReg.intercept_)
print(myLogReg.coef_)
print("")
myLogRegUpdateCandidate = LogisticRegression(solver = 'newton-cg', max_iter=1000, fit_intercept=True, random_state=1)
myLogRegUpdateCandidate.fit(XX, Y)
y_probCandidate = myLogRegUpdateCandidate.predict_proba(XX)
candidateMinusTwoLogLik = 2*len(Y)*log_loss(Y, y_probCandidate)
print(myLogRegUpdateCandidate.intercept_)
print(myLogRegUpdateCandidate.coef_)
print("")
print(chi2.sf(currentMinusTwoLogLik-candidateMinusTwoLogLik, 1))
```

Comment: You can't train a linear model with multiple inputs that have perfect linear correlation. It's the logistic regression, not sklearn.

Comment: So... After battling a long time with the LogisticRegression function, I have realised how the problem occurred! It has by default a penalty='l2', which is a regularisation of the coefficient estimates, a 'Ridge'-like or LASSO-like penalisation. If I set penalty='none' I get the expected results!